# Why does $\sqrt{-ab}=\sqrt{-a}\sqrt b$ hold?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

> Why does $\sqrt{-ab}=\sqrt{-a}\sqrt b$ hold, where $a,b\in\Bbb R$?

I know that splitting sqrts is not permissible for complex numbers generally, eg, $\sqrt{-1\cdot-1}\ne\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$.

Also, is $\sqrt{-a}$ unique or we can assign two values, one additive inverse of other?

**Edit/Context:** My question was based on the last paragraph of this example from Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra:

[image]

Here, even though $D=f^2D'$ be negative both sides, they have taken square root and concluded $\sqrt D=f\sqrt D$.

Comment: What you have written is wrong even for reals. What if $a = b = 1$? There is no $\sqrt{-1}$. It's not $i$. That and $-i$ both have square $-1$ and neither is properly called "the" square root.

Comment: For me $\sqrt{a}=\{x\in \mathbb{C}: x^2=a\}$ for any complex number $a$, so what you wrote doesn't make any sense

Comment: $\sqrt{-ab}=\sqrt{-a}\sqrt b$ does not hold.

Comment: @Adam: the operator $\sqrt.$ is usually defined to be a function (main branch), and a number $x$ has two square roots, $\pm\sqrt x$. The multifunction definition is not convenient.

Comment: @Adam, will you please look at my context? Thanks for your earlier comment. So, are the authors wrong?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thanks for your comment. So,  in above newly added picture, what will be $\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: In this context what matters is that whichever of the two square roots of $D$ you adjoin to the rationals you get the same bigger field. $D$ can be positive or negative. Your concern about the square root sign is a red herring.

Comment: @EthanBolker, so is it true that $\sqrt {-ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt -b$ where $a,b>0$?

Comment: If $b > 0$ and if $a \in \mathbb R$ then $\sqrt{-ab} = \sqrt{-a}\sqrt{b}$ which may or may not be imaginary depending on whether $a$ is negative or non-negative.  But for that to hold $b$ *must* be non-negative real.

Comment: $\sqrt{-\frac 12} = \sqrt{-\frac 24} = \sqrt{(\frac 12)^2*-2} = \frac 12\sqrt{-2}$.

Comment: "Here, even though D=f2D′ be negative both sides, they have taken square root and concluded D−−√=fD−−√."  Thats acceptable because $f^2$ is positive.  (Actually, the did *not* conclude $\sqrt D =f\sqrt{D'}$  They concluded $\sqrt D = |f|\sqrt{D'}$.  [They didn't even conclude *that*; they concluded $\sqrt D \in \mathbb Q[\sqrt{D'}]$.])

Comment: @Silent My very first comment answers your last question to me. I don't think I don't think I can be of any further help..

Comment: In general in complex analysis you should avoid $\sqrt{}$ entirely as they are ambiguous.  However as we don't care about actual square roots but field extensions and $F[d] = F[-d]$ that isn't such a big concern here.  We can, IMO for *this* excercise, take $\sqrt{-a}$ where $a > 0$ to be $i\sqrt{a}$ although *in general* we can't usually distinguish whethe $\sqrt{-a}$ "should" be $i\sqrt{a}$ or $-i\sqrt{a}$.  Both would be valid. But as $F[i\sqrt{a}]=F[-i\sqrt{a}]$ it doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does $\sqrt{-ab}=\sqrt{-a}\sqrt{b}$, where $a,b∈\mathbb R$?

It doesn't.  It holds if $a,b \ge 0$ and then then $\sqrt{-ab} = i\sqrt{ab}=i\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}= \sqrt{-a}\sqrt{b}$.  However if  $a$ and $b$ are negative or complex more care needs to be given.

Note: if *one* of them is non-negative real,  Say $b \ge 0$ then we *can* say that $\sqrt{-ab} = \sqrt{-a}\sqrt{b}$ whether $-a$ is positive of negative.  However it must be that $b$ is non-negative.

Or if $-a$ is positive.  Then $-a = u\ge 0$ and $\sqrt{-ab} = \sqrt{ub}=\sqrt{u}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{-a}{b}$.

But $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is only valid if one or the other is non-negative real.  Otherwise.... well, care must be taken.

> My question was based on the last paragraph of this example from Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra:

The last paragraph is to note that any rational $D$ can be uniquely expressed as $f^2*D'$ where $f$ is rational and $D'$ is a "square-free" integer.  (I will admit the definition is a bit clunky.)

In other words if $D \in Q$ then $D = f^2D'$ and $\sqrt{D} =\sqrt{f^2D'} = f\sqrt{D'}$.  This *is* acceptable because $f^2 > 0$.

Pf: $D = \pm \frac ab; a,b \in \mathbb Z; a\ge 0; b> 0; \gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Let $a = \prod p_i^{m_i}$ be the unique prime factorization of $a$ and let $b = \prod q_i^{n_i}$ be the unique prime factorization of $b$.

Now each $m_i$ and each $n_i$ is either odd or even.  Let $m_i' = \frac {m_i}2$ if $m_i$ is even and let $m_i' = \frac {m_i - 1}2$ if $m_i$ is odd.  (In other words let $m_i' = \lfloor \frac {m_i}2 \rfloor$. )  Likewise define $n_i'$ in the same ways so that $n_i' = \frac {n_i}2$ if $n_i$ is even and let $n_i' = \frac {n_i - 1}2$ if $n_i$ is odd.

Then $a = \prod p_i^{m_i} = \prod p_i^{2m_i'}\prod_{m_i\text{ is odd}} p_i = (\prod p_i^{m_i'})^2 *\prod_{m_i\text{ is odd}} p_i$.  Let $e = \prod p_i^{m_i'}$ and $D_1 = \prod_{m_i\text{ is odd}} p_i$.  Notice that $D_1$ is a prime free integer.

Likewise $b = \prod q_i^{n_i} = \prod q_i^{2n_i'}\prod_{n_i\text{ is odd}} q_i = (\prod q_i^{n_i'})^2 *\prod_{n_i\text{ is odd}} q_i$.  Let $g = \prod q_i^{n_i'}$ and $D_2 = \prod_{n_i\text{ is odd}} q_i$.

So $D = \pm\frac ab = \frac {e^2D_1}{f^2D_2} = \pm\frac {e^2D_1D_2}{g^2D_2^2} = (\frac {e}{gD_2})^2(\pm D_1D_2)$.

Let $f=\frac {e}{gD_2}$ is a uniquely determined positive rational number and $D' = \pm D_1D_2$ is a square-free integer also uniquely determined.

As $D$ was not a square of a rational, it is not possible that $D' = 1$.  But it is possible that $D' = -1$.  But $D'$ is squarefree, an integer and possibly positive and possibly negative.  But $f^2$ is a square (and therefore positive) of a rational number.

Comment: Thank you so much for this awesome reply, and so many comments.

Answer (score 0):

You just gave a counter-example to your own question. That is if you pick $a=1$ and $b=-1$ the equation turns out to be $\sqrt{-1\cdot -1} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$.

The reason for this (as you guessed) is that $\sqrt{-1}$, or any square above complex numbers is not uniquely determined. For example $\sqrt{-1}=i$ in one hand, while in the other hand $\sqrt{-1}=-i$, unlike real numbers there is no "natural" way to distinguish between $i$ and $-i$ (because there is no such thing "a positive complex number").

We can define the square root of a complex number $a$ to be any number which satisfies the equation $x^2-a=0$. In this setting it is easy to see that if $b$ is one solution, then it's negative, $-b$ is another solution (and there are no more solutions).